# Unable to create chef user: Connection refused connecting to https://127.0.0.1/users/

Tags: chef-infra, ubuntu-server

I'm installing chef server per the instructions at https://docs.chef.io/release/server_12-3/install_server.html#standalone on an Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS machine. When I run the command to create a chef administrator:

```
sudo chef-server-ctl user-create ...(etc)...
```

I get back:

```
ERROR: Connection refused connecting to http://127.0.0.1/users/
```

I'm installing chef on a machine that already has Apache2 running. Running `chef-server-ctl status` shows that all services are running. However, I notice two things that indicate potential problems to me, for which I lack the skills/experience to fix:

- There is no `/users/` directory under `/var/www/html/`. I don't know if this is expected or not; I'm sure there is some other way to tell Apache to alias the /users/ URL to a place on disk somewhere, but I don't know what it is.
- When I run `curl https://127.0.0.1`, I get error "`curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to 127.0.0.1:443`".

If I run `netstat -an|grep :443`, I do see that there is a process (presumably Apache) listening on port 443.

Can anyone suggest further troubleshooting steps to take?

Answer (score 5):

Chef Server is an appliance that expects to control the box for the most part. You will need to shut down whatever is listening on ports 80 and 443 (i.e. uninstall Apache or install Chef Server on its own VM).

Comment: Fixed by stopping apache `service apache2 stop`